# how to add images to database in django with out showing the path of images in choosen button

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class ProductForms(forms.ModelForm):
    images1 = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput,)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields =  '__all__'
```

How can I make it so that the path to the images isn’t shown in the rendered html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="file" name="picture" />
```

Use this, but change the name as you wrote in the model

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to modify your css with something like:

```css
css-selector-here {
    display: none;
}
```

In order to not show that UI element. You can also do this my modifying the template, but I wouldn’t. This is cleaner and way easier.